# Replace laptop pre-installed with windows with ubuntu and install windows on virtual box as genuine windows

Tags: windows, virtualbox, laptop

I was always wanted to try this. I want to purchase laptop with windows(win 8.1 as latest) pre-installed. And then dual boot into ubuntu where I would like to install same copy of windows into virtual machine/VirtualBox without getting genuine error. Since its on same machine I should not be breaking the genuine policy but the windows will detect it as different machine. So what is solution?

I would be using both OS for different softwares so it would make sense if I could use both softwares together at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I don't think this is an Ubuntu question but more of a Windows question, but I will give you a quick pointer - It is most certainly possible to do, but it does break the Microsoft terms of service and therefore is illegal. Because you will be dual booting, you will already have a copy of windows installed on the computer, adding a second copy in a VM will count as a second copy. You can view the full terms of service [here](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing).

This is a screenshot showing the relevant section:

[image]

If, however, you would like to run your VM using the existing windows install you already have on your computer, and thereby circumventing any legal issues that may arrive from a second windows install, there are a few posts and tutorials which may be of help:

[Is there a way to access my current windows installation within a VM environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334604/is-there-a-way-to-access-my-current-windows-installation-within-a-vm-environment)

http://betanews.com/2012/03/01/install-windows-8-on-oracle-virtual-box/

Comment: Ok what if I wipe windows from laptop with backup partition kept safe and then I only load windows on virtual environment. How would I make sure that windows will detect the base system hardware instead of virtual environment's hardware?

Comment: This post may also be of interest to you - [Is there a way to access my current windows installation within a VM environment?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334604/is-there-a-way-to-access-my-current-windows-installation-within-a-vm-environment)

Comment: Also [here](http://betanews.com/2012/03/01/install-windows-8-on-oracle-virtual-box/) is a tutorial which will also help

Comment: Yes this answer I am looking for. Please post as seperate answer or update this answer with description of steps to do in brief. I will accept as answer.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include the links I provided.